# Complete intersections in complex and algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables

I'm wondering why (and therefore also if) the notions of "a projective variety/submanifold of projective space is a complete intersection" as used in algebraic geometry and the theory of, say, Riemann surfaces agree.
The following are the precise versions of these notions I refer to:

In algebraic geometry:
An algebraic $A$ subset of $\mathbb CP^n$ of dimension $k$ is called a complete intersection if its vanishing ideal $I(A) \subseteq \mathbb C[X_0,...X_n]$ can be generated by $n-k$ polynomials.

In complex geometry:
A (complex) submanifold $A$ of $\mathbb CP^n$ of dimension $k$ is called a complete intersection if it arises as the (projective) zero-set of a homogeneous, holomorphic map $f:\mathbb C^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb C^{n-k}$ such that the Jacobian of $f$ has rank $n-k$ at every $0 \neq x \in \mathbb C^{n+1}$ with $f(x) = 0$.

The precise question now is:
Given a submanifold that is also an algebraic subset (e.g. smooth algebraic subset), do these notions of complete intersection coincide? And if so, do the required sets of maps agree?
Edit: Of course I am also interested in a proof of the result.

I am aware that every holomorphic, homogeneous map is actually a polynomial (just by Taylorexpansion).
As an example I can easily see that the twisted cubic curve in $\mathbb CP^3$ is not an algebraic geometry complete intersection, but how does one see that this is also not the case using the complex geometry defintion?

Comment: Hi Francesco, why Chow's theorem? Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: right, I misread the question. I delete the comment


Comment: These notions will coincide if one demands, in the second of them, that rank of the Jacobian be $n-k$ *everywhere on* $f^{-1}(0)\setminus \{0\}$. 

Comment: I mean, they coincide if in the first definition, which makes sense for singular subvarieties as well, you assume that the algebraic subset $A$ is smooth.

Comment: @Serge Lvovski: Of course, the condition only has to hold on the actual solution set, I edited that above. Thank you! But why is the statement true?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\star$ By Thm. I.5.1, page 32 of Hartshorne the Jacobian condition is equivalent to that every local ring of $A$ is a regular local ring, i.e., that $A$ is a non-singular variety.

From AG to CG:
This is (probably) the easy direction: Let the coordinate functions of $f$ be the generators of the ideal $I(A)$. By $\star$ and the assumption that $A$ is smooth/non-singular it follows that the Jacobian of $f$ has maximal rank.

From CG to AG:
Consider the ideal generated by the coordinate functions of the map $f:\mathbb C^{n+1}\to \mathbb C^{n-k}$ and call it $J$. The zero set of $J$ is $A$ and the proof of $\star$ shows that the Jacobian condition implies that localizing $\mathbb C[X_0,\dots,X_n]/J$ at any maximal ideal gives a regular local ring, so $A$ is smooth. Regular local rings are domains, so in particular this implies that $\mathbb C[X_0,\dots,X_n]/J$ has no nilpotents or in other words $J=\sqrt{J}$ and therefore $J=I(A)$. By design it is generated by $n-k$ elements.

Comment: Is that a high-brow way of saying "a bunch of polynomials with full-rank Jacobian on their common zero-set generate a radical ideal"? If so, why is that? Or do you know a good reference?

Comment: I'm sorry if my answer came across as smug, it was not intended. I was simply trying to understand your answer (which I still do not, simply because I don't know a whole lot about schemes). My question was only whether, that is the statement your answer boils down to, should one try to understand it "non-schematically". Also I do know how I would finish one direction of the proof, given that this is the case, but not how your answer comes into play. again this may well be due to ignorance on my part.

Comment: OK, no problem. Sometimes comments come out differently than they were intended. You don't need to know anything about schemes actually to understand this answer. I hadn't known your background.... So, yes, that's what it means. Anyway, I will try to include a more detailed answer later, but I can't do it right now. Cheers!

Comment: OK, here is a more detailed proof. If this is still not clear enough, then try to be more specific in what is not clear and with which direction you are having trouble.

Comment: From AG to CG: Why does being a submanifold imply algebraic smoothness? From CG to AG: being a domain locally implies being a domain? On a different level: This uses "guns", where for the moment I consider the Nullstellensatz and the behaviour of local rings "guns", because they use more notion/maschinery than the question. I had been hoping for a more elementary proof, can this one be decoded into a short elementary one?

Comment: AG to CG: algebraic smoothness (over $\mathbb C$) is equivalent to the (algebraic) tangent space being the same dimension as the variety. This follows from being a manifold. CG to AG: This can be translated to somewhat elementary, but not short *and* elementary. Since your AG def includes the ideal of the variety you can't do anything without the Nullstellensatz. Being a domain locally implies being a domain for something connected, but you actually only need that it has no nilpotents which follows from the local condition. 

Comment: All right! Thanks a lot for your patience.